# Leaflet Directive performance issues with 7539 GEOjson features

Tags: leaflet, geojson, performance, angular

I'm using [this](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/layers/overlay-geojson-example) example for my [map](https://map.tonearth.com/bg/) but it seems that the map performance is pretty bad when zoomed. Currently the map have 7539 geojson objects (features) and in the future they will be around 9500. I tried using the `preferCanvas` option, but I did not see any difference. Also I was looking at the [VectorGrid](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#vectorgrid-slicer) plugin, but I dont see how can I implement it in my case.

Example of how the features work:

```
$http.get("sold.geojson").success(function (data, status) {
            angular.extend($scope.layers.overlays, {
                sold: {
                    name: 'Sold',
                    type: 'geoJSONShape',
                    data: data,
                    visible: true,
                    layerOptions: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#ff0000',
                            weight: 1,
                            fillOpacity: 0,
                            opacity: 1,
                        },
                        onEachFeature:
                            function (feature, layer) {
                                targetLatLong = feature.properties;
                                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                                    $http.get("file.php?landId=" + feature.properties.id).success(function (data, status) {
                                        var landDiv = document.getElementById('sold-detail-' + feature.properties.id);
                                        landDiv.innerHTML = data;
                                    });
                                });
                                const popup = L.responsivePopup({className: 'buyPopup'}).setContent('<div class="buyPopup" id="sold-detail-' + feature.properties.id + '">Loading...</div>');
                                layer.bindPopup(popup);
                            },
                    },
                },
                selectedLand: {},
            });
            // Put the cells on an associative array
            $scope.cells = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var cell = data[i];
                $scope.cells[cell['properties']['type']] = cell;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try performance without base `imageLayer` layer, which is complex SVG image?

Comment: @TomazicM No, but I need the image. The image itself is loading fast (~1s) but the objects are causing this.